# Pull Request not merging even though all policies are met

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

We're running into a problem where sometimes a pull request in Azure DevOps does not auto merge even though all the checks pass.

We've configured policies on the target branch (besides the regular build validation and minimal reviewers) that adds a required status and one optional status. Both do not use iterations and are only added when first posting a status to the pull request. Only squash merges are allowed.

The build validation pipeline checks some things, in a separate stage, and [posts the required status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to the pull request. If it is not met it will post a status notSet, otherwise it will be succeeded.

A [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) has been configured to send a message to a Azure Function whenever there is a change in the reviewer votes. This Azure Function will [restart the stage of the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/stages/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) validation so the status on the PR can be updated.

At the end of the pipeline we post the optional status (state as succeeded) without waiting on the response.

Even though we configure all PRs to autocomplete with a squash merge it sometimes happens that it will not trigger the auto complete. We end up with a pull request that passes all the checks yet doesn't merge to the target branch.

Something I did notice is that the optional status is added as required instead of being mentioned as ignored by auto-complete.

Making this status check optional again on the PR will trigger a PR evaluation which then completes the merge. But this is obviously not how it should be.

Is there any information on this issue and how do we fix it so our process will work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to double check on the Pull request page, make sure all the policies are met, no merge conflict, all status checks are met.

If it's **sporadic** that auto-completed doesn't work which caused by the optional status check becomes required one, you can go to branch policy setting, make sure no one else change the setting. If the setting is correct, suggest to report on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) , it could a potential bug. Here is a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pull-Request-doesnt-automatically-compl/10082816) which was fixed before.